# Finding difference in means using KS Test (Weighted data)

Tags: sas, statistics

I am trying to find the difference in means in my two samples. The distribution is not normal hence I have to resort to KS test. Now, the data is weighted. In proc t-test, there is an option of mentioning weight in the command, like this:

```
proc ttest data=input;
var variable_x;
class variable_y;
weight weight;
run;
```

Is there a similar thing for KS test in npar1way procedure? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good SO question, you should check the documentation to find the answer.

Comment: I did check in the documentation, but I could not find a similar thing, hence the ask.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this as a SO question.  The presence of the answer in the documentation is not a barrier to a question being good.  Most of the questions here can be answered from documentation after all.

Comment: No, it's still a 'statistical' type question, how to deal with weighted data in a non parametric test. And he could have said there wasn't the line in the documentation.

Comment: I would appreciate if you guys could help me with this. I have been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: @Reeza If the question is "How to do X in SAS" it's correct here.  If it's "What statistic whatever is correct theoretically" it belongs in [stats.se].  Some are okay in both places (this probably would be).

Comment: @VaishakNChandran I'm not a statistician, so I certainly can't give you a good answer.  I will say that the `freq` statement is the closest to a weight, though I think it probably only works with integer weights.  You may want to look at `SURVEYREG` or `SURVEYLOGISTIC` as those are better for weighted data.

Comment: @Joe those won't work for a non parametric test.

Comment: Yes, I belive proc survreyreg assumes normality of data.

Comment: Not a stats person like I said, just a programmer, so certainly will defer to you all here.  I will note that Peter Flom recommends it in a similar situaiton [here](http://marc.info/?l=sas-l&m=132800761809084), though the OP is not as clear in indicating that their data is non-normal (though they suggest they would usually use NPAR1WAY similarly).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044375/how-to-calculate-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-statistic-between-two-weighted-samples

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193439/two-sample-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-with-weights

Comment: I think you're going to have to hardcode it, but I would simply ask SAS Support first and see what they say.